# Querying tables in BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, json, group-by, google-bigquery

**Background**

I have a table with 1 column 'data' which contains 'JSON' in BigQuery shown below.

```
 data    
 {"name":"x","mobile":999,"location":"abc"}
 {"name":"x1","mobile":9991,"location":"abc1"}
```

Now, I want to use groupby functions:

```
SELECT
    data
FROM
    table 
GROUP BY 
    json_extract(data,'$.location')
```

This query throws an error

> expression JSON_EXTRACT([data], '$.location') in GROUP BY is invalid

So, I modify query to

```
SELECT
    data, json_extract(data,'$.location') as l
FROM
    table 
GROUP BY
    l
```

This query throws error

> Expression 'data' is not present in the GROUP BY list

**Query**

How can we use JSON fields in group by clause?

And what are the limitations (in context of querying),in having columns populated with JSON.

Comment: it is not clear - what result you expect to have? can you provide example of "aggregated" row in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping something by location, but you are not using an aggregate function for `data` field, hence the compiler doesn't know which to pick or what you aggregate on the source.

Just to illustrate the example I compiled this test query which works using `group_concat`:

```
select group_concat(data),location from
(
select * from
(SELECT '{"name":"x","mobile":999,"location":"abc"}' as data,json_extract('{"name":"x","mobile":999,"location":"abc"}','$.location') as location),
(SELECT '{"name":"x","mobile":111,"location":"abc"}' as data,json_extract('{"name":"x","mobile":111,"location":"abc"}','$.location') as location),
(SELECT '{"name":"x1","mobile":9991,"location":"abc1"}' as data,json_extract('{"name":"x1","mobile":9991,"location":"abc1"}','$.location') as location)

) d
group by location
```

and returns:

```
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--+
| Row | f0_                                                                                               | location |  |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--+
| 1   | {"name":"x","mobile":999,"location":"abc"},"{""name"":""x"",""mobile"":111,""location"":""abc""}" | abc      |  |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--+
| 2   | {"name":"x1","mobile":9991,"location":"abc1"}                                                     | abc1     |  |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--+
```

[BigQuery's Aggregate Functions documented here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)

Comment: ok,nice,but can this method be scalable if i have large number of rows?

Comment: If you are talking about BigQuery yes, there even petabyte scale operations run fast

Comment: The inner selects are pure example to run a static query without a table. But your data is in a table so you query only that.

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT location,
  GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(REPLACE(data, ',"location":"' + location + '"', '')) AS data
FROM (
  SELECT data,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data,'$.location') AS  location,
  FROM YourTable
)
GROUP BY location
```